# Grouping child processes in node-webkit or atom/electron

Tags: node-webkit, electron

I am doing some research into building a cross-platform desktop application using web technologies. Both [node-webkit](http://nwjs.io/) and [electron/atom](http://electron.atom.io/) would be perfect for the job.

However, with it being a multi-window app, my clients aren't too keen on the vast number of processes which chromium creates (2 per window).

I've looked into passing some different command line switches, `--single-process` and a few others but they only seem to cause the app to crash on startup.

I then looked at node itself, the closest i got here was the `process` API exposes methods to set the group PID. Alas, this is unsupported on windows which is my primary target platform.

I don't know if you've ever googled "hide process from task manager", it's starting to look a bit scary and deep-webish. there must be an easier way.

Does anyone have some suggestions or maybe a different technology?

Comment: Do they actually have an issue with multiple processes being created, or do they really care about how things look in the task manager?

Comment: It's just how it looks in the task manager, they aren't super-technical so arguing the security benefits dont do much good. As far as they are concerned, it looks like a waste of resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible, sorry! The code that allows single-process in Chromium is busted and bitrotted

Answer (score 1):

I've been dealing with the same issue and can confirm that as of Electron version 1.4.10 the `--single-process` flag is still crashing the app.
I ended up using `--process-per-site`. It groups the processes per web site/domain. If you are using Angular in your app (with the same index page), all Browsers will be launched with the same process.
https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/process-models

Comment: This doesn't seem to work and the application crushes as soon as you try to access electron from within the child window.